# Is this relation in 3NF as well as in BCNF?

Tags: database-normalization, 3nf, bcnf

Suppose a relation schema `R(A,B,C)` and the FDs are

> {A -> B, B -> C}

So the superkeys are `{A}, {A,B}`

Now if we decompose it into **3NF** it will be

> R1(A,B) with FD {A -> B} and R2(B,C) with FD {B -> C}

Is it in **BCNF**? I can't determine. Since `B` was not a superkey in `R` does `{B -> C}` in `R2` violates **BCNF**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{AB} is a superkey, but it's not a candidate key. (It's not a minimal superkey.)  The decomposition

- R<sub>1</sub>(**A** B)
- R<sub>2</sub>(**B** C)

is in *at least* BCNF.

Informally, a relation is in BCNF if every arrow is an arrow *out* of a candidate key. **B** is a candidate key in R<sub>2</sub>.

The relation R is *not* in BCNF. The only candidate key in R is A; the FD B->C has an arrow that's *not* out of a candidate key.

In truth, both R<sub>1</sub> and R<sub>2</sub> are much stronger than BCNF. They're both in 6NF.