# BCNF, 3NF, and candidate keys

Tags: database, 3nf, bcnf, candidate-key

I am having issues understanding how to determine if relations are in BCNF, 3NF, and in general identifying the candidate keys of a relation.

Consider relation `R = (A, B, C, D)` with the functional dependencies:

```
AB -> C
C -> D
D -> A
```

The questions included:

> a. list the candidate keys of R
>   b. determine if R is in BCNF or 3NF.

The solution resolves

> a. 3 candidate keys for R are AB, BC, and BD.
>   b. R is in 3NF, but not in BCNF.

I've read through [What is the difference between 3NF and BCNF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19749913/what-is-the-difference-between-3nf-and-bcnf) and can understand the difference between 3NF and BCNF when referring to non-arbituary words within a database schema. I am ultimately lost when trying to determine the relationships with a reduced relation, as given in the problem.

Could someone explain how the candidate keys were determined above, and why R is in 3NF but not BCNF?

Comment: Your question is too broad for SO. In practice you are asking all the important issues on relational theory. Read a good book on databases, see for istance this [aswer](https://www.quora.com/What-are-some-good-books-about-databases).

Comment: These steps are in any textbook covering normalization. Dozens are free online. Please don't ask us to write you anther. Name & quote/paraphrase one, show the steps of your work following it & ask a question re the first place you are stuck. Also these are all nevertheless easily found duplicate [so] questions. Although that's a poor source for learning about the relational model.

Answer (score 5):

You are asking several questions at the same time.

1. How to compute the keys of a relation. In general, the simplest way is to compute the closure of every single combination of attributes and determine which ones are superkeys. From this set of superkeys, find those that are minimal: these are the candidate keys.
2. How to determine if a relation is BCNF.

FOr this you don't needs keys. All you need to do is test that every non-trivial functional dependency, the left hand side is a superkey of the relation.

How do you determine this for a FD? Simply compute the closure of the left hand side of the FD. If the result is all the attributes of the relation, then it is a superkey.

3. How to determine if the relation is 3NF?

FDs must be in Canonical form: one attribute in the right hand side.

For every non-trivial FD, either the left hand is a superkey (as in BCNF) or the right hand side is part of a key (any key).

This is a *very* good video that explains the differences:

[BCNF vs 3NF](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7W8j1UkdjwI)

Comment: One step at a time... I am struggling to understand how the closure is determined with the abstract R=(A,B,C,D) and further extracting the superkeys to identify the candidate keys. For the BCNF, how are the A,B,C,D entities of R used to determine non-trivial functional dependency? I edited the original question if that helps.

Comment: Further searching to determine if a relation is BCNF I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23591784/is-this-relation-in-3nf-as-well-as-in-bcnf?rq=1, which uses candidate keys to determine if the relation is in BCNF